# maven release plugin fails with timeout from git

Tags: git, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I get the below error while doing mvn release:perform. Seems like its a timeout issue while cloning the project into target/checkout folder. Am not sure how to solve the issue.
I did git clone manually and it worked but through mvn release plugin it fails with below error.
Any help would be appreciated!!

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:perform (default-cli) on project ProjectX: Unable to checkout from SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-clone command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Cloning into '/mnt/c/projects/JBoss7.4/ProjectX/target/checkout'...
[ERROR] Connection to git.vgt.volvo.com closed by remote host.
[ERROR] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
[ERROR] fatal: early EOF
[ERROR] fatal: index-pack failed
```

My scm configuration in pom looks like below

```
<scm>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git.vgt.volvo.com:29418/vgt/caretrack/cct/portal/ProjectX</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git.vgt.volvo.com:29418/vgt/caretrack/cct/portal/ProjectX</developerConnection>
        <tag>ProjectX-1</tag>
    </scm>
```

Comment: Have you check if the remote repository is cleanly prunes based on `index-pack failed` ? I would check that repo and try `git gc --prune=now`

Comment: i read that git gc will remove unnecessary files and optimize the repo. Is that what you want me to try before doing mvn release?

Comment: Can you give a hint what kind of system is in the backend Gitlab, Github or Gitea where the git repos are hosted? If so I would suggest to optimise the repo fist...

Comment: But i face this issue when i do only through mvn release:perform. Otherwise i normally could do git clone without any issues